# /v1.0/me/drive/search returns empty object for file field

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

When I search for [`DriveItems`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveitem) with the `/v1.0/me/drive/search` endpoint, items which are Files (e.g a `.pdf`) should be returned with a [file resource](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/file) in the `file` field according to the documentation. This file resource should contain the fields `hashes` and `mimeType`.

However, when I retrieve `DriveItem` results that are definitely files, I only receive an empty object in the `file` field. Is there something missing in my query or is this a bug.

The exact URL I am using to query is:

```
/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='test')?$select=webUrl,file,name,lastModifiedDateTime,createdBy,lastModifiedBy,createdDateTime,folder,image,id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we don't return either the hash or the mimeType for search results. But I have made the change to atleast return mimeType. Hash is a harder fix and requires a bit of work. Thanks for bringing this to our attention. I will keep track of this issue and hopefully get to it in the near future.